# convert image into base64 in wp8

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, base64

I have an image taken from my phone gallery, like below:

```
private void StackPanel_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    PhotoChooserTask pct = new PhotoChooserTask();
    pct.Show();
    pct.Completed += pct_Completed;
}

void pct_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();

    if (e.ChosenPhoto != null)
    {
        img.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        imgphotochoser.Source = img;
    }
}
```

Now I want to save this image in a database, via a web service. So, I'm required to convert this image into a base64 string, but how can I do this?

I've tried this, but it throws an exception:

```
public string imagetobase64(image image,
  system.drawing.imaging.imageformat format)
{
    using (memorystream ms = new memorystream())
    {
        // convert image to byte[]
        image.save(ms, format);
        byte[] imagebytes = ms.toarray();

        // convert byte[] to base64 string
        string base64string = convert.tobase64string(imagebytes);
        return base64string;
    }
}
```

Comment: C# is a **case-sensitive** language

Comment: @DGibbs:The type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: but which assembly? i dont know which essembly for drowing and it also give error in "save"

Comment: @DGibbs:when i am tring to add system.drowing dll at that time it will give error "a reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project" how can i solve problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply convert the `byte[]` to a base64 `string`:

```
byte[] bytearray = null;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    if (imgphotochoser.Source != null)
    {
        WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)imgphotochoser.Source);

        wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, 46, 38, 0, 100);
        bytearray = ms.ToArray();
    }
}
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
```

Base64 to `byte[]`:

```
byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(s);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length))
{
    ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366212/convert-imagesource-to-base64string-wp8

Comment: I'm using this code to encode an image to save in a SQLite database, but when I try to decode, I get "FormatException", "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string" when trying to convert fromBase64String.... any ideia why?

Comment: How about convert image to 64 bit & covert 64 bit to image?