# Convert ImageSource to Base64String - WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, base64, imagesource

am working on WP8application, I have few images in location Resources\Graphics\ i am trying to display images from these folder, but its not picking the path.

Here is my code :

`<img src=\"/Resources;component/Graphics/"+ImageName).Append("\" ") this is in my string which i am using in my WebBrowserControl.`

`WebBrowserControl.NavigateToString(html); // here html is a string which has all the html code in it.`

But its not display the images.

So i want to convert the ImageSource --`Resources;component/Graphics/"+ImageName` to Base64String how to do it?

I have looked into many examples but none of them is compatible for WP8.

Comment: Do you only want to display the images in your web Browser?

Comment: Yes i want to display images in WebBrowser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `StreamInfo` by using this:

```
Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources;component/Graphics/"+ImageName", System.UriKind.Relative));
```

Then you can read this stream into an byte array. After that, use `Convert.ToBase64String()` to get what you want. Try this. Maybe you can read the MSDN document to find how to use Stream.

```
var img = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources;component/Graphics/"+ImageName", System.UriKind.Relative));
var buffer = new byte[img.Stream.Length];
img.Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
img.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
```

Comment: can you please help me with the read the stream into an byte array, as i am not getting how to proceed further

Comment: With this code i will be able to get the Base64 string and use it, if i am correct

Comment: It works fine, thanks but is there no other way that i can display images in Web browser control ? Do i need to mandatorily convert image source to Base64 string

Comment: @Goofy `WebBrowser` can't access file packed into resource. Maybe you can try to make your Image file as Content and fill the `img` tag src with its full path. I try that once worked. Not sure if that still worked now.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple - load your image into a byte array and call

`System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray)`.

That being said, this will not result in displaying the image. The NavigateToString requires html. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: can please show me the code? because i have searched for it and didnt find any solution

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

```
            byte[] bytearray = null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                if (bmp != null)
                {
                    var wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);

                    wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, 46, 38, 0, 100);
                    bytearray = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            if (bytearray != null)
            {
                // image base64 here
                string btmStr = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
            }
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to explain why your answer is *the answer*

Comment: @k4nchjr0 "bmp" refer to?