# base64 encodedimage data.imageURL is coming too large in windows phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, base64

I am getting encoded image in base64 from server in windows phone 8. Some images are displaying properly but some images are not dispplaying. For those images which are not showing the data.imageURL is too much large. In android and ios data.imageURL is fine and showing image.

Comment: Your code is invalid..
you can check more here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108183/online-tool-to-decode-base64-string-to-png

Comment: Yes it is not decoding and giving error "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters." Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `BitmapImage` to encode to `base64`?

These might be helpful!

[Converting image to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874733/)

[convert image into base64 in wp8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234256/)

Comment: I cannot edit the code on server side. I am setting the src of <img> to data.imageURL coming from server. I cannot edit the code on server side. Is there any method to compress the image and then set to src.

Comment: but you're getting down those images from locally from server isn't it?